# How to remove most highlights from scrollbar in JetBrains IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, highlight

I am exploring code with a lot of problems and my scrollbar is looking like

[image]

I don't see any sense of flooding entire scrollbar with yellow. Also it prevents me to see something important like scrollbar knob. Can I disable scrollbar notifications only? I would like to remain problems highlighted in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Errors and Warnings, disable the **Error stripe mark** for all the items.

[image: error stripe]